# Implementing a one to one relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So, firstly, I think I have a design problem, but not sure how to solve it.

I have two tables :

```
-------
Company
-------
CompanyId
CompanyName
-----------
```

And :

```
-------                   
Company Administrator
-------
AdminId
AdminName
-----------
```

My idea is the relationship to be one to one, because one company can have ona company admin and one company admin cna have one company.

My question : 
Do I have to put a foreign key in each of the tables, or should I implement it in some different(possibly better way).

I can't really merge the tables because in my app I want the company admin to create the company.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Robert! Are you saying that you want the Company admin to have one company and a company to belong to an admin?

Comment: Yes, i guess. One company must have only only one admin, and one admin can have only one company as well. My Idea for the webpage I'll have is the following : The admin first registers himself and then creates his company from his own profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading your question as:

**CompanyAdministrator has one Company** and **Company belongs to CompanyAdministrator**.

If this correct then:
- You want the `Company` to keep track of which `CompanyAdministrator` it belongs to. Your table will look something like this:

```
    Company: 
     - id
     - company_name
     - any other attributes of the company you want to track
     - company_administrator_id

    CompanyAdministrator: 
      - id
      - any other attribute of the comanpy_administrator you want to track.
```

Basically, company_administrator_id lives in the company table.

Answer (score 0):

When you have 1 to 1 relation , you can use each primary key of tables as foreign key in the other table for example :

```
    ------
    **Company**
    -------
   CompanyId
   CompanyName
    Admin_id 
    -----------
    -------                   
    **Company Administrator**
    -------
    AdminId 
     AdminName 
    -----------
    **OR**
    ------
    Company
    -------
    CompanyId
    CompanyName
    -----------
    -------                   
    Company Administrator
    -------
    AdminId
    AdminName
    Company_id
    -----------
```